# Terminology of "G over H"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

I am trying to find the definition of G/H (which is read as "G over H", "G modulo H", or "G mod H").  I believe that, in this case, G is a group and H is a subgroup of G.

Comment: Do you know anything about quotient groups? This is what you're looking for.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$.  Then, the cosets of $H$ form a group $G/H$ under the binary operation $(aH)(bH)=(ab)H$.
The group $G/H$ is the **factor group** (or **quotient group**) of $G$ by $H$.

Answer (score 2):

It depends if you are considering the quotient set, or the quotient group. Define: $$x \sim_L y \iff xy^{-1} \in H$$

We can also write this as $x \equiv_L y \mod H $. Here, $L$ is for "left". You can define it the same way for right. Then, we have the class: $$\bar{x}_L = \{y \in G \mid x \equiv_L y \mod H\}$$

Then, we define $G/H = \{ \bar{x}_L \mid x \in G\}$. If $H$ is normal in $G$, then in the end won't matter if we use the relation by the left or by the right, and we can define a operation in the quotient set, by: $$\bar{x} \cdot \bar{y} := \overline{xy}$$

It has to be proven that the operation does not depend on the representant of the class that you pick. Then $(G/H, \cdot)$ is called the quotient group.